# Reading the values of an array generated with push

Tags: javascript

I am storing values in an array like this. 
 I want to be able to test the values contained in Routenumber and SerialNumber.
 If Routenumber == "" do something
 if SerialNumber == "None" do something

How can I acheive this in my for statement? What I have below just returns an object.

```
$('#ValidateAcctAssign').click(function() {
    var values = [];
    $("#container-grid input[name=CatId]:checked").each(function() {
        row = $(this).closest("tr");
        values.push({
            CatId: $(row).find("input[name=CatId]").val(),
            Routenumber: $(row).find("td div.routenum").text(),
            SerialNumber: $(row).find("td div.primrep").text()
        });
    });
    console.log(values);
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[1] == "" || values[2] == "None") {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(count);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access to object's property you can use dot notation

You need this `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i].Routenumber == "" || values[i].SerialNumber == "None") {
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it would be that simple